# How to use toolbar in react native android application

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning `react-native` programming where I am trying to integrate http://react-native-material-design.github.io/installation for material design.

I want to use this http://react-native-material-design.github.io/components/toolbar view in my application as there is no such documentation for how to use it.

Can anyone help me how can I use this view in my application. Thanks in advance.

PS: I do not want to use this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html

Answer (score 3):

Apart from not knowing what navigator you're using, with `react-native-router-flux` you can easily setup a NavBar (or Toolbar in Android words) by simply adding `navBar={MyCustomNavBar}` to the Scene where you want your toolbar to exist,

```
<Scene sceneStyle={{marginTop: Metrics.navBarHeight}} component={HomeScreen} key="home" navBar={MyCustomNavBar}/>
```

and

`import MyCustomNavBar from './components'` at the top of your navigator.

CustomNavBar can be anything you can imagine. You may add Icons, Buttons, Logos or even animated search bar. Just mind that in React Native, toolbars are positioned absolute, and they have a fixed height, therefore all the Scenes in Navigator must have a marginTop style, in order to prevent content being overlapped. An example MyCustomBar can have a wrapper view such as

```
render() {
 return (
   <View style={containerStyle}>
      ...
   </View>
 )
}
```

with containerStyles of

```
container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    height: Metrics.navBarHeight,
  }
```

**NavBar heights are not the same in Android and iOS (54 and 64 respectively)**

Comment: I installed npm i react-native-router-flux --save but I am getting an error `unable to resolve module  react-native-router-flux`

Comment: Can you reset your watchman and perform react-native run-ios or android

Comment: This seems to be a different issue rather than package itself. @Williams

Comment: Yes, I did react-native run-android, but do not know how to reset watchman ?

Comment: Can you do some googling? Let me know if you come up with nothing

Comment: When you install or change npm modules it's best to stop any packager instances that are running then start them again using `react-native run-android` again. This is because npm modules are not watched for changes.

Comment: @Williams any news?